# How to store conditional data in RDF

Tags: sparql, rdf

I want to store  some facts in pure RDF data (ttl) like :

```
:Person :hasGender :Male, :Female ;
             :drink :Liquor, :softDrinks .

if (:someone :hasGender :Male) then
     :someone :drink :Liquor ;
else
     :someone :drink :softDrinks .

:Susan  a :Person ;
       :hasGender :Female .
```

and then read this rdf data (ttl) by Sparql or other app (rdf4j or rdflib) ,  and get :

```
:Susan :drink :softDrinks .
```

I want to use pure RDF as much as possible to store data, rather than OWL, N3, RDF-star or SHACL, but I can reconstruct a new N3 or shacl file from these rdf data, and then get infered result.
I wonder if this is possible in RDF, an how can I modify this RDF data?  Thanks.

Comment: plain RDF is just plain explicit statements. And even if you use RDFS, this kind of inference is **not** possible. That's exactly why people came up with OWL and SWRL on top of RDF - to make it more expressive. Either you use something on top of RDF, or it just is not possible. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think what you said makes sense.I'm just trying to store simple conditional data for specific application scenarios.   I think so far this approach basically meets my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got It done.  here is data.ttl :

```
 @prefix : <http://example.org/#> .
:Person :drink :someLiquid .
:someLiquid :hasRule :rule1, :rule2.
:rule1 :forGender :Male ;
       :beverage :liquor .
:rule2 :forGender :Female ;
       :beverage :softDrinks .       
    
:Susan  a :Person ;
       :hasGender :Female .
:John a :Person ;
       :hasGender :Male .
```

here is the sparql query:

```
    PREFIX : <http://example.org/#>
     SELECT ?person ?gender ?beverage
     WHERE {
        :Person :drink :someLiquid .
        :someLiquid :hasRule ?rule .
        ?rule :forGender ?forGender ;
              :beverage ?beverage .
        ?person a :Person;        
             :hasGender ?gender .
      FILTER ( ?gender = ?forGender )
    }
```

and I get the result:

```
1    person,   gender,   beverage
2    :Susan,  :Female,  :softDrinks
3    :John,   :Male,    :liquor
```